# trouble getting jQuery mobile to work

Tags: android, jquery

I'm new to android programming and I'm trying to use Phonegap and jQuery Mobile.

I have configured Eclipse, Android SDK and Phonegap and this is working correctly but I have trouble with jQuery.

Here is my test page for jQuery:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
    var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

    document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

    function deviceReady() {
        $('#title2').html('THIS WORK');
      deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
    }

    $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
      jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
    });

    $.when(deviceReadyDeferred,  jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);

    function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
        $('#title2').html('THIS WORK');
    }

    </script>
   </head>
   <body>

     <table width=100% height="50" border ="0">
     <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="title">TEST</div>
            <div id="title2">TEST2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I expected to get "TEST2" replace by "THIS WORK" but this is not the case when I launch the Android emulator.

May someone help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help

Best Regards.

Florent

Comment: question. you said it didn't work on 'emulator', then it works on real android device?

Comment: Not I haven't test on a real device as the script is so basic that I didn't think the issue is related to the use of the emulator

Comment: OK I think I got it. jQuery mobile is not enough to run this script and I need to include jQuery as well. Look like jQuery mobile is only for building interface... I will close my question after confirming I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that I missed to include jQuery library.
Adding it solved my issue:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```